# Security of using sha(secret + rand)

Tags: hmac, sha-256

I have come across some security implementations in which party A will compute MD = sha256(secret + rand) and transmit MD and rand to a counterpart B. If the second party knows the secret, then when it computes sha256(secret + rand), it will match that from sender A and validate it.

This may be a loaded question, but is this secure at all? Meaning, would it be very hard for an attacker to discover the secret given the resultant hash and the random number?

Part 2: Another potentially loaded question
Would it be more/less secure to instead use an hmac using the secret as the 'data'? So HMAC(rand, secret) ?

The goal of both security systems is to ensure that both A and B possess the same key K without transmitting it, but is either more secure? Are these implementations 'traditional' or more of a 'cluge'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using HMAC is more principled and flexible here, because HMAC with a random secret key is a [pseudorandom function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family), while `sha256(secret + nonsecret)` isn't.

In your case where the non-secret is a random value there might not be a security difference. But I mentioned also *flexibility*, because this sort of authentication scheme—when implemented with a proper pseudorandom function like HMAC—doesn't need a random value.  A counter or wall clock time will do.  In fact, if you've seen those two-factor authentication tokens or apps that display a six-digit code that changes every minute, those are based on the [TOTP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm), which is basically `hmac(secret, current_time / refresh_interval)`.

Comment: So, the HMAC is more suited for this, and from what you're saying is that instead of a random number you could/should use a timestamp, so it means a bit more. Maybe you can use it to ensure that the code was not intercepted and re-transmitted at a later date? Like the 2 factor rolling codes

Comment: I'm not saying you *should* use a timestamp, only that you *could*.  It would, for example, save you the overhead of transmitting the `rand` value along with `MD`, by using instead a changing value that is predictable to both parties A and B at the time the authentication happens.  The use of a proper MAC guarantees that it's not a problem that the timestamp is also predictable to an adversary.  While in the scheme you describe, we appear to be relying on the fact that the `rand` values are unpredictable to adversaries.